# Infinite loop When use many realm db （realm-cocoa）

Tags: ios, realm

I use realm store app data ([RLMRealm defaultRealm]). And I need a independent realm to store user behavior statistical data (StatistisDB). Importantly, this db design can't change. But when I debug on Simulator, open the realm, it loop on this function infinite.

[image: Infinite loop function]

StatistisDB:

```
RLMRealmConfiguration *config = [RLMRealmConfiguration defaultConfiguration];
NSString *fileName = @"XRKAnalyticEvent";
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
config.fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[paths[0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.realm", fileName]]];
RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm realmWithConfiguration:config error:nil];
```

Comment: What version of Realm do you use? 
Does the problem always reproduce? Can you provide a reproducible project?

Comment: It reproduce everytime, when I debug on simulator and open Realm Browser. Is it a I/O problem

Comment: I cannot reproduce that issue. Could you please give more info? And can you make sure not to use 32-bit simulators? Realm cannot open the file from 32 bit and 64-bit processes simultaneously.